# Displaying a grid of thumbnails with C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my C# / WPF application I want to display a grid of image thumbnails from a directory tree of image files (currently .bmp's, but eventually other formats).    In the future I'll probably want to allow the user to either click on a thumbnail to see a bigger version, or mouse over it to see some technical details, but right now all I want to do is display the thumbnails.

The number of images is not predictable and my instructions are to enable scrolling if there are more images than I can fit on a screen (rather than, say, shrinking the thumbnails).

I have a recursive routine to walk the tree and identify files to display . . .

```
   private bool WalkTree(String sRoot)
    {
        string sDirectoryName;
        string sFileName;
        int iDirectoryCount = 0;
        DirectoryInfo DirInfo;

        DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sRoot);
        // Get a list of all the files in this directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in DirInfo.GetFiles("*.bmp"))
        {
            sFileName = fi.Name;
            // DO SOMETHING WITH FILE FOUND HERE
        } 

        // Now get a list of all the subfolders in this directory.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in DirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            sDirectoryName = di.Name;
            WalkTree(sRoot + "\\" + sDirectoryName);  //recurse!!
            iDirectoryCount++;
        }
        return true;
    }  // End WalkTree
```

So what's a good way to do this?   What XAML control should I use to put all these in?  A Grid?  Can I add rows to that and make it scroll as I recurse and discover more files?   Or should I walk the tree twice -  once to get a count and configure the rows and columns in my page and the second time to actually display the thumbnails?   Or am I thinking about this all wrong?

I feel like this problem must have been solved enough times in the past that there must be a canonical design pattern for it but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Use a ListBox with a UniformGrid as its items panel.

Comment: ... and then populate it as I go along, i.e., 1-pass in the _WalkTree()_ routine?   That sounds reasonable.   What do others here think?    Is there a canonical design pattern for this?

Comment: Fill a list and then databind to it.

Comment: @poke -  if I did databinding wouldn't all the images have to get loaded into memory first?    I know how to do databinding to collection classes and databases but I'm not sure how to do it to a set of _n_ image files in a directory tree where neither the number of files nor the topology of the tree is known until it's discovered at runtime.

Comment: That depends a lot on what you’re databinding. You could just populate the list with the file names for example. That way, the list wouldn’t take much memory.

Comment: A collection of image paths bound to an items control with a wrap panel as the items panel template. In the template put a border with an image control in it. Bind the image width and height to properties which the set can control and you've got customisable thumbnail sizes.

Comment: Use a ListBox like @poke said and also set IsVirtualizing = true.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Instead of recursively calling your function why don't you just use the `AllDirectoreies` option? `foreach (FileInfo fi in DirInfo.GetFiles("*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories))`

Answer (score 5):

The comments describe how to do the layout part. It is relatively easy and what solution to use depends on the actual layout. `UniformGrid` is fine. It would be sufficient to use an `ItemsControl` here:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <UniformGrid />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="100" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Question is: What is `Images`, the property you bind the `ItemsSource` to? What you have is a list of strings with the filenames, what you need is a collcetion of `ImageSource`s. There is no way around loading the images to memory. Still you need to do it efficiently, if you don't want your app to consume huge amounts of memory when the images are numerous and large. An option is to scale the images to thumbnails. Secondly, as you are scaling the images, this is a good opportunity to crop them as well to get fixed aspect ratios and make the grid look nice.

Images needs to be a collection of `BitmapImage` here in order to be bindable to the `ImageSource` property of the `Image` control:

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Images { get; set; }
```

And this is basically what goes to `// DO SOMETHING WITH FILE FOUND HERE`:

```
var image = CreateBitmap(path);
var width = image.PixelWidth;
var height = image.PixelHeight;

// Crop image (cut the side which is too long)
var expectedHeightAtCurrentWidth = width*4.0/3.0;
var expectedWidthAtCurrentHeight = height*3.0/4.0;
var newWidth = Math.Min(expectedWidthAtCurrentHeight, width);
var newHeight = Math.Min(expectedHeightAtCurrentWidth, height);            
var croppedImage = CropImage(image, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);

// Scale to with of 100px
var ratio= 100.0 / newWidth;
var scaledImage = ScaleImage(croppedImage, ratio);
Images.Add(scaledImage);
```

With the following functions to create, scale and crop the image:

```
private static BitmapImage CreateBitmap(string path)
{
    var bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    bi.EndInit();
    return bi;
}

private BitmapImage ScaleImage(BitmapImage original, double scale)
{
    var scaledBitmapSource = new TransformedBitmap();
    scaledBitmapSource.BeginInit();
    scaledBitmapSource.Source = original;
    scaledBitmapSource.Transform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
    scaledBitmapSource.EndInit();
    return BitmapSourceToBitmap(scaledBitmapSource);
}

private BitmapImage CropImage(BitmapImage original, int width, int height)
{
    var deltaWidth = original.PixelWidth - width;
    var deltaHeight = original.PixelHeight - height;
    var marginX = deltaWidth/2;
    var marginY = deltaHeight/2;
    var rectangle = new Int32Rect(marginX, marginY, width, height);
    var croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(original, rectangle);
    return BitmapSourceToBitmap(croppedBitmap);
}

private BitmapImage BitmapSourceToBitmap(BitmapSource source)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var image = new BitmapImage();

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);

    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
    image.EndInit();
    memoryStream.Close();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: When I tried pasting the XAML I got the dreaded **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**
as soon as I pasted it

Comment: Hmm, no idea. I've been using most of the code. Can you pack an example project? I'll have a look at it then.